# Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values in plot.phylo

Tags: r

I'm able to plot a dendrogram with hclust class, but when I'm trying to convert it to as.phylo in ape package it gives me the error for the plot

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

Any idea what can cause the problem?

Thanks,

```
mymerge<-Merg_Mat
myheight<-cumsum(abs(diff(ll)))
myhclust=list(order=lab,merge=mymerge,height=myheight)
class(myhclust)="hclust"
plot(as.phylo(myhclust),edge.col=colors,edge.width = 2, edge.lty =1,font=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the figure is too big for your window, try to output it into a file.

```
pdf("my_plot.pdf")
plot(as.phylo(myhclust),edge.col=colors,edge.width = 2, edge.lty =1,font=1)
dev.off()
```

If you read the `plot.phylo` function code, you'll see that `xlim` is set to `c(0, depth_of_your_tree)`. So if it is too big for the device (window or postscript, [see here](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/When-200-inch-page-limit-broken-q36927.aspx), it simply is because your tree is too deep.

PDF maximum page size is so big it should be able to hold your figure.

Comment: I'm actually trying to save the output in postscript file! Does the dimension of that matters too? Thanks,

Comment: Well, I think thats not the case! I just need to know where in phylo class, x comes from!

Comment: So the pdf export did not work neither ? It is still a problem that one of `xlim` dimensions is set to a non existing value. `xlim` is set in `plot.phylo`, but you can give it as an argument `x.lim=c(xmin, xmax)`to solve your problem.

Comment: What shall I put in x.lim! I tried the range of labels which are from 1 to 54, but it didn't work! just two lines connecting each other, which I believe is the most top level on the dendrogram.

Comment: `xlim ` must be a vector of size 2 `c(xmin, xmax)`. You should put `xmin=0`, that's what is done in the plotting function. xmax must be big enough to fit your entire tree, but not too big or the error will arise again. You should try different values for `xmax`

Comment: Thanks, I put the xmax=1000000 and It worked! but it caused a lot of margin below the dendrogram! I need to figure it out! Thanks once again